# Challenge: Add descriptions around the arrows in a Tikz flow chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows, text, decorations

I attempt to make a flow chart looks like this:

[image]

My question is that, is there some way that I can **add some text descriptions below and above the line/body of the arrows** that linked between the boxes and the ellipses? For example, we can use `\stackrel` or `\underset` or `\overset` on the `\leftarrow` or `\rightarrow`, when we want to add descriptions above/below the arrows when we write the text. How about in tikz?

```
    \documentclass[letter,10pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains, calc, decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}

    \usepackage{pifont}
    \newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
    \newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
    \newcommand{\done}{\rlap{$\square$}{\raisebox{2pt}{\large\hspace{1pt}\cmark}}
    \hspace{-2.5pt}}
    \newcommand{\wontfix}{\rlap{$\square$}{\large\hspace{1pt}\xmark}}


    \begin{document}

    \tikzset{
    box/.style={
        rectangle,
        draw,
        text width=8em,
        text centered,
        },
    block/.style={
        rectangle,
        draw,
        text width=10em,
        text centered,
        rounded corners
    },
    cloud/.style={
        draw,
        ellipse,
        minimum height=3em,
         text width=6.5em
    }
    }



\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (m)[matrix of nodes, column  sep=2cm,row  sep=8mm, align=center, nodes={rectangle,draw, anchor=center} ]{
  &  |[box]| {1}              &  \\
|[box]| {2}    &       &\\
&  |[cloud]| {3}   & |[cloud]| {4} \\
&|[cloud]| {5} &\\
};
\draw [line width=1.pt,  dashed, ->] (m-1-2) edge (m-3-2);
\draw [line width=1.pt, dotted, <->]  (m-2-1) edge (m-3-2);
\path [>=latex, line width=2.pt, <->] (m-3-2) edge (m-3-3);
\path [>=latex, thick, dash dot, ->] (m-3-2) edge (m-4-2);
\path [>=latex, thick,  dash dot, ->] (m-3-3) edge (m-4-2);
\draw [line width=1.pt,dotted, ->] (m-2-1) edge (m-4-2);



\end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Sure, `\path [>=latex, line width=2.pt, <->] (m-3-2) edge node[above] {Above}(m-3-3);` would place on the arrow

Comment: Actually, for the standard LaTeX case I would use `\xrightarrow{abov}` (`mathtools` package) instead of `\stackrel`.

Comment: Not much of a challenge :(.

Answer (score 10):

With the use of the `quotes` tikz library:

[image]

I took a liberty and also changed the positioning of the nodes. You can still stick with your solution with `matrix` and adequately changes the node names:

```
\documentclass[letter,margin=3mm, 10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes, shapes}% removed not used libraries
% removed not used fonts and new commands

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
node distance = 6mm and 18mm,
   box/.style = {rectangle,
                 draw,
                 text width=8em,
                 align=center,
                 },
 block/.style = {box,
                 rounded corners
                 text width=10em,
                 },
 cloud/.style = {ellipse,
                 draw,
                 minimum height=3em,
                 text width=6.5em,
                 align=center,
                 },
 every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\footnotesize, text=blue}
                            ]
\node (n1) [box]                        {1};
\node (n2) [box,below left=of n1]       {2};
\node (n3) [cloud,below=of n1 |- n2]    {3};
\node (n4) [cloud,right=of n3]          {4};
\node (n5) [cloud,below=of n3]          {5};
    \begin{scope}[line width=1 pt, >=Stealth]
\draw [dashed,->]   (n1) edge ["text"] (n3);
\draw [dotted,->]   (n2) edge ["text"] (n3);
\draw [dotted,<->]  (n2) edge ["text"] (n5);
\draw [line width=2 pt, <->]    (n3) edge ["text"] (n4);
\draw [dash dot, ->]    (n3) edge ["text"] (n5)
                        (n4) edge ["text"] (n5);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**addendum:**
in case, that you like to have some edge labels sloped, you only need to add option `sloped` to edge label- for example:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, 10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes, shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
node distance = 6mm and 18mm,
   box/.style = {rectangle,
                 draw,
                 text width=8em,
                 align=center,
                 },
 block/.style = {box,
                 rounded corners
                 text width=10em,
                 },
 cloud/.style = {ellipse,
                 draw,
                 minimum height=3em,
                 text width=6.5em,
                 align=center,
                 },
 every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\footnotesize, text=blue}
                            ]
\node (n1) [box]                        {1};
\node (n2) [box,below left=of n1]       {2};
\node (n3) [cloud,below=of n1 |- n2]    {3};
\node (n4) [cloud,right=of n3]          {4};
\node (n5) [cloud,below=of n3]          {5};
    \begin{scope}[line width=1 pt, >=Stealth]
\draw [dashed,->]   (n1) edge ["text"] (n3);
\draw [dotted,->]   (n2) edge ["text",sloped] (n3);
\draw [dotted,<->]  (n2) edge ["text",sloped] (n5);
\draw [line width=2 pt, <->]    (n3) edge ["text"] (n4);
\draw [dash dot, ->]    (n3) edge ["text"] (n5)
                        (n4) edge ["text" ', sloped] (n5);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

note: `["text" ', sloped]` is shorter version for `["text", swap, sloped]`. both move labels on opposite side of edges.

Answer (score 6):

As percusse mentions:

```
\documentclass[letter,10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains, calc, decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}

\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\newcommand{\done}{\rlap{$\square$}{\raisebox{2pt}{\large\hspace{1pt}\cmark}}
\hspace{-2.5pt}}
\newcommand{\wontfix}{\rlap{$\square$}{\large\hspace{1pt}\xmark}}


\begin{document}

\tikzset{
box/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw,
    text width=8em,
    text centered,
    },
block/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw,
    text width=10em,
    text centered,
    rounded corners
},
cloud/.style={
    draw,
    ellipse,
    minimum height=3em,
     text width=6.5em
}
}



\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (m)[matrix of nodes, column  sep=2cm,row  sep=8mm, align=center, nodes={rectangle,draw, anchor=center} ]{
  &  |[box]| {1}              &  \\
|[box]| {2}    &       &\\
&  |[cloud]| {3}   & |[cloud]| {4} \\
&|[cloud]| {5} &\\
};
\draw [line width=1.pt,  dashed, ->] (m-1-2) edge node[midway,left]{A} (m-3-2);
\draw [line width=1.pt, dotted, <->]  (m-2-1) edge node[midway,above]{B} (m-3-2);
\path [>=latex, line width=2.pt, <->] (m-3-2) edge node[midway,above]{C} (m-3-3);
\path [>=latex, thick, dash dot, ->] (m-3-2) edge  (m-4-2);
\path [>=latex, thick,  dash dot, ->] (m-3-3) edge node[midway,below]{D} (m-4-2);
\draw [line width=1.pt,dotted, ->] (m-2-1) edge (m-4-2);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This should be seen as an addition to @marmot's answer. The positioning of the label with e.g. `below` or `left` can mean that the label overwrites the line if you have sloped lines. For example the line between 2 and 5 can be

```
\draw [line width=1.pt,dotted, ->] (m-2-1) edge node[midway,left]{Label} (m-4-2);
```

to get

[image]

To avoid this you can add a distance to the position, like `left=10pt`. Alternatively you can position the label relative the label instead of the line. While `left` means left of the line, you can instead state `anchor=north east` to put the upper right corner of the label midway of the line. Another alternative is to use `sloped` labels to let it follow the line. In the second case I used `pos=0.6` to avoid having the label too close to the line 2<->3 (`midway` is the same as `pos=0.5`).

```
\draw [line width=1.pt,dotted, ->] (m-2-1) edge
node[midway,left=10pt]{Label} 
node[midway,anchor=north east,blue]{Label 2}
node[pos=0.6,above,sloped,red]{Label 3} 
(m-4-2);
```

[image]